# running time error when trying to implent a keyword frequency counter in my parser java

Tags: java, parsing, runtime-error, frequency

I want to implement my input reading method into my main class, I want use my code to parse. It's been fixed now. thanks. 
        String x;
        int count = -1;=
        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            count++;
            x = str.nextToken();
            word[count] = x;
           System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);

```
    }

    System.out.println("---Frequency---");

    // create unique words
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {
            unique[i] = word[i];
        }
    }

    // measuring frequency
    int[] measure = new int[10];

    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
        if (Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[a])) {
            measure[a] += 1;
            System.out.println(unique[a] + " : " + measure[a]);
        }
    }
}
}

    private List<String[]> termsDocsArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String> allTerms = new ArrayList<String>(); //to hold all terms
    private List<double[]> tfidfDocsVector = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    /**
```

Comment: This is actually a compile time error. You ignored errors when compiling and this was detected while trying to execute your code.  Fix the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with your code

```
String text = "Professor, engineering, data, mining, research";
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
        String word[] = new String[10];
        String unique[] = new String[10];
        String x;
        int count = -1;
        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            count++;
            x = str.nextToken();
            word[count] = x;
           System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);

        }

        System.out.println("---Frequency---");

        // create unique words
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

            if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {
                unique[i] = word[i];
            }
        }

        // measuring frequency
        int[] measure = new int[10];

        for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[a])) {
                measure[a] += 1;
                System.out.println(unique[a] + " : " + measure[a]);
            }
        }
```

should be in it's own method like .

```
private void doSomething(){
      //This variable will hold all terms of each document in an array.

        String text = "Professor, engineering, data, mining, research";
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
        String word[] = new String[10];
        String unique[] = new String[10];
        String x;
        int count = -1;
        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            count++;
            x = str.nextToken();
            word[count] = x;
           System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);

        }

        System.out.println("---Frequency---");

        // create unique words
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

            if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {
                unique[i] = word[i];
            }
        }

        // measuring frequency
        int[] measure = new int[10];

        for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[a])) {
                measure[a] += 1;
                System.out.println(unique[a] + " : " + measure[a]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Secondly in ur given code u have written like

```
int count = -1;=
```

which accounts to this error Syntax error on token "=", { expected.It should be

```
int count = -1;
```

And since all your code is simply written in class without any method so it is giving you the error saying { expected.

Please make sure you have copied the code correctly.

Comment: you can contact me at d.synchronized@gmail.com. I will surely try to sort your issue.

Comment: I emailed you mr anand